# .net Core WebAPI Forbid method returns status code 500 instead of 403

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, http-status-codes

I don't understand, what's wrong with my code.

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace DE.ZA.MobilePickingApp.Controllers {
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : ControllerBase {

        [HttpPost("Login")]
        public ActionResult<Guid> Login([FromBody]string password) {
            if (password == "My Super Safe Password")
                return Ok(new Guid());
            else
                return StatusCode(403);
        }
    }
}
```

When I replace `return StatusCode(403);` with `return Forbid();`, instead of returning HTTP status 403 to the client, it returns status 500. Why is that?

Comment: are you sure, you are invoking that action in the same way ?

Comment: @Manish Thank you! So my "workaround" is actually the correct solution, as it seems.

Comment: it is giving you 500 because your API is actually failing, it's trying to see some authentication middleware logic but unable to find it. so that's why it's giving 500.

Comment: yes, correct. if you are not using any authentication logic just use StatusCode method

Comment: @Manish Thank you. In the first iteration of our software, there will just be a simple password check.

Comment: if you want to confirm whether the APIs are failing or not, you can use the event viewer. happy to help :)